# persisting esxi /bootbank/boot.cfg across reboots

Tags: vmware-esxi, boot, console, serial

i have a serial console connected to my esxi 5.5 server. and the configs work fine for the pxe install. however, upon reboot my console no longer works:

i believe i need to change the file /bootbank/boot.cfg to include:

```
kernelopt= installerDiskDumpSlotSize=2560 no-auto-partition text nofb com1_baud=57600 com1_Port=0x3f8 tty2Port=com1 gdbPort=none logPort=none
```

however, upon reboot this change is lost.

how do i persist this change on esxi?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the change outlined here http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp#com.vmware.vsphere.install.doc_50/GUID-E17AB108-7AA0-43DF-8616-48625CD018DF.html#GUID-E17AB108-7AA0-43DF-8616-48625CD018DF using the vSphere Client.

That will make it permanent.